# Java program getting terminated before Resultset.next()

Tags: java, eclipse, resultset

My program is get terminated just after printing `hello in getImportance beg`. Why so? My `MAIL` table has values.

```
Connection connection = connectToDatabase();
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet mailset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUBJECT from MAIL");
            ResultSet keywordset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SKEYWORD FROM KEYWORD");
            System.out.println("hello in getImportance beg"); 
            while(mailset.next())
            {               
                System.out.println("hello in first while"); 

                while(keywordset.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("hello in second while"); 
                    if(mailset.getString("SUBJECT").equals(keywordset.getString("SKEYWORD")));
                    {
                        System.out.println("hello in if"); 
                        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE'" + 1 + "'");
                        stmt.executeUpdate("COMMIT");
                    }
                }
            }
            mailset.close();
            keywordset.close();
            connection.close();
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

---

Thanks everyone for the replies. Defining the second `ResultSet` after first `while` did the trick.

Comment: May be your `mailset` is empty.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Are you sure that the query you are passing actually returns something?

Comment: You haven't shown any exception handling - my guess is that an exception is being thrown. How are you running this?

Comment: As a side note, connection objects by default have auto-commit on so the `COMMIT` execute update at the end doesn't make a lot of difference. If you actually want proper transaction demarcation, turn off auto-commit on connection and use `commit` and `rollback` methods on the `Connection` object. [Please read](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop is obviously not running.

Check the result of mailset.next()

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are trying to obtain two `ResultSet`s from a single `Statement`.

From the `java.sql.Statement` documentation: "By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists."

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the `mailset`. it delivers probably no result. You can check it with `System.out.println(mailset.next());` before the first loop, or debug it.

Another issue on the second resultset. As I understand: you try to iterate each time over keywordset. Then you need to go to the beginning of the result set after the second while loop `(while(keywordset.next())` using `keywordset.beforeFirst()` .